# Can rails avoid using template for a function return mail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates, actionmailer

I have a mailer class and a controller calls a function in the mailer class like:
    MyMailer.my_email.deliver
The function looks like this:
    def my_email
      ...
      return mail(...)
    end
But I have to provide a template my_email.html.erb in views/MyMailer otherwise rails report missing template error. Even just an empty template will let it work. Obviously I don't want to have an empty template to just make it work, so is it possible to avoid using the tempalte?

Comment: If you avoid using the template, what will render your email? Not sure why you'd want to do that.

Comment: I thought the layout render the email?

Comment: Typically, a template nests inside of a layout. A layout basically sets up some `html` and calls `yield`, which your template will use to render its content. You can check out the [Rails reference](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html) on this topic. Read section 3.2 and replace the phrase "content from the view" with its synonym, template.